# Array split into 2 and map the corresponding objects and put them in the resultant array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of array of objects similar to this:

```
arr = [{
    val: 1,
    ts: 123
}, {
    val: 2,
    ts: 125
}, {
    val: 3,
    ts: 120
}, {
    val: 4,
    ts: 113
}, {
    val: 5,
    ts: 117
}, {
    val1: 6,
    ts: 143
}, {
    val1: 7,
    ts: 193
}, {
    val1: 8,
    ts: 187
}, {
    val1: 9,
    ts: 115
}, {
    val1: 10,
    ts: 116
}]
```

The length of the array is always an even number. Now basically I'd like to split them in 2 halves

```
split1 = [{ val:1},  {val :2}, ......{val:5}]
split2 = [{val1:6},{val1:7},.......{val1:10}]
```

Now I have to map over these arrays and combine their fields(first item of array1 with first item of array2 and so on) into one single object and add an extra id to it such that result will look like

```
final = [{val:1, val1:6 , id:1} , {val:2, val1:7,id:3} , {val:3, val1:8,id:3},{val:4, val1:9,id:4},{val: 5, val1:10, id:5}]
```

This should hold for all arrays of even length and I want to make it a dynamic one. Keys will never be repeated inside source array

What I have tried is:

```
var res= a.splice(0, arr.length/2);
var c = a.map((val, ind) => { {val, res[ind]} })
```

Can someone guide here?

Comment: You con't have a repeated key

Comment: yeah source array will not have any repeated items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close, some minor fixes

1. wrap map function implicit return with `()` instead of `{}`
2. for adding computed value you need to assign key name explicitly
3. need to destructure val or need to access `val.val`

```js
const arr = [{ val: 1}, {val: 2}, {val: 3}, {val: 4}, {val: 5}, {val1: 6}, {val1: 7}, {val1: 8}, {val1: 9}, {val1: 10}];

const firstHalf = arr.slice(0, arr.length / 2);
const secondHalf = arr.slice(arr.length / 2);
const final = secondHalf.map((val, ind) => ({
  ...val,
  ...firstHalf[ind],
  id: ind,
}))

console.log(final);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can we make it dynamic. Rather than having to hardcode val, val1

Comment: @random1594 what do you mean by dynamic here ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: inside your secondHalf.map you have added val,val2 as keys which are sort of hardcoded. Can we some how, make this a dynamic. Like merge the fields of objects item by item post spilt

Comment: @CodeManiac Guess your result has only 4 items, should it not be 5? as you are splitting an array of length 10. I think it secondHalf should be changed to     const secondHalf = arr.slice(arr.length / 2, arr.length);

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution

```js
const arr = [{ val: 1},{val: 2},{val: 3}, {val: 4} , {val:5},{ val1: 6},{val1: 7},{val1: 8}, {val1: 9} , {val1:10}]

const split = arr => [arr.slice(0, arr.length/2), arr.slice(arr.length/2, arr.length)]

const splitedArr = split(arr);

const merge = arr => {
  const merged = []
  for(let  i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++){
    let newObj = {...arr[0][i], ...arr[1][i], id:(i+1)}
    merged.push(newObj);
  }
  return merged;
}

const mergedArr = merge(splitedArr);
console.log(mergedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried
>
> ```
> var res= a.splice(0, arr.length/2);
> var c = a.map((val, ind) => { {val, res[ind]} })
> ```

You're quite close. To make the `map` callback syntactically valid and create the desired object, it should be

```
var res = a.splice(0, arr.length/2);
var c = a.map((val, ind) => {
    return {val: val.val, val1: res[ind].val1, id: ind+1};
})
```

or

```
var c = a.map((val, ind) => {
    return Object.assign({id: ind+1}, val, res[ind]);
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Bergi, how can we make this a dynamic one, Rather than having to hardcode val, val1

Comment: @random1594 What other kinds of objects do you need to the code to work with? And what would the expected result be respectively?

Comment: what I meant was inside return {val: val.val, val1: res[ind].val, id: ind+1} statement, it looks like keys are hardcoded. can we some how, make this a dynamic. Like merge the fields of objects item by item post spilt

Comment: @random1594 Sure you can make that part of the code dynamic. It's just unclear what exactly you want - examples of other inputs would help. What do you mean by "*merge the fields of objects item by item post spilt*"?

Comment: Oops, I didn't realise that you already had different kinds of objects in the original array, with different properties (`val` vs `val1`). Now it's clear, I've updated.